# adding new value to List overwrite previous value

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, foreach, reference-type

I'm trying to add to a list. If I move the declaration into a loop it works fine but too slow, if I don't, add method overwrite previous values.

what should I do?

```
Dim _obj As New ClassDAL.Site.SalesPoint
    Dim _r = _obj.GetCities
    Dim temp As New ClassDAL.Site.SalesPoint
    Dim myList As New List(Of ClassDAL.Site.SalesPoint)


    For Each row In _r


        temp.FullCode = Convert.ToString(row.Item(0))
        temp.CityCode = Convert.ToString(row.Item(1))
        temp.Karm = Convert.ToInt32(row.Item(2))
        temp.Name = Convert.ToString(row.Item(3))
        myList.Add(temp)
        temp = New ClassDAL.Site.SalesPoint

    Next

    Return myList
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your varible inside the loop as it is a reference type, otherwise in the next loop you are modifying the reference to the last item you created.

You could try doing something like this, but I don't think it will be any quicker:

```
For Each row In _r
    myList.Add(New ClassDAL.Site.SalesPoint With {
        .FullCode = Convert.ToString(row.Item(0))
        .CityCode = Convert.ToString(row.Item(1))
        .Karm = Convert.ToInt32(row.Item(2))
        .Name = Convert.ToString(row.Item(3))
        })

Next
```

Comment: it almost takes 4-5 second to return list

Comment: The time is in the constructor of `SalesPoint` then. Hows many rows do you have in `_r`?

Comment: just 81. i don't understand why it takes soo long.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. post the code of the constructor of `SalesPoint` and ask why it is taking ~50ms to run through